# rendering multiple loops in a pug template

Tags: node.js, mongodb, pug

please in my code below the first loop works fine in my pug template but the second does not but when I remove the first loop the second loop begins to function.I have tried all possible means but to no avail please is there something I am doing wrong? Results and ashantiresults are data  retrieved from a mongo db database  collections
 ``

```
if results
  each result,i in results
   |#{result.category} posted by #{result.username}
   a.cat(href="/showaccra/"+result.id)
    img.meta(src="/"+result.pic)  
 if ashantiresults
  each ashantiresult,i in ashantiresults
   |#{ashantiresult.category} posted by #{ashantiresult.username}
```

``

Comment: Check your indentation. Both `if` statements should be at the same indentation level, but it looks like the second one has space before it currently.

Comment: sorry but when I indent it to be on the same level it still does not work